# How to center text on customized and resizeable button using bootstrap 4 only

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a problem with button text. I have customized the width and height of a button and when I resize, its text remains no more in center on some screen sizes in a debugging mode.

**Html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>ICT</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" charset="utf-8" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>

<body class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
    <div @fade class="img-wrapper">
      <img [src]="imgPath" class="img-fluid">
      <div class="img-overlay">
        <button routerLink="/test" 
                class="btn btn-success fill-container text-center testButton">
                TEST
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

**CSS**

```
.img-wrapper {
    position: relative;
}

.img-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 31%;
    left: 13.5%;

    width: 34%;
    height: 4%;
}

.testButton {
    font-size: 3vw;
    line-height: 20px;
}
.fill-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

**Update**

Here is the image where I want html button to replace the button on image

[image]

Please have a look I have added the image on which I want to place an html button with same width and height so that it hides the image button.

Comment: add code for this button, html and css. `text-center` should do as class name

Comment: read the manual, it has all the information in there

Comment: Some folks are downvoting already because they expect you to post CODE. Posting your current code is absolutely essential when answering coding related questions because otherwise all answers would be based on pure guesswork and you certainly don't wanna that. So, post your current code here.

Comment: fine, I am doing that

Comment: @Ylama please up vote, I have added code to it

Comment: So, what you want is a larger button with the text centered in it, correct? Does the button need to be a particular size or just larger button than normal?

Comment: Don't worry about upvotes, I'm here and will help you sort this out.

Comment: I need to set a specific size in percentage

Comment: please don't down vote, otherwise I'll be blocked. Please don't do this

Comment: i made a duplicate of your code and the text is always centered. Even mobile. what browser are you using

Comment: chrome I am using, in iPhone 8 mode it becomes ugly

Comment: Please have a look I have added the image on which I want to place an html button with same width and height so that it hides the image button.

Comment: You should post the HTML for the entire page. I changed the size of the button without any issues. Post the HTML for the entire page.

Comment: try adding `text-center` as class to the `div` that surounds it, like this -- > `<div class="img-overlay text-center"></div>`

Comment: added whole html of my web page

Comment: I applied text-center with img-overlay class but it didn't work. When I changed to iPhone 8 mode, it crased the view

Comment: what its so confusing how that happens, maybe add a screen shot of the mobile view?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to center text on button in different screens in bootstrap4 or css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48497165/how-to-center-text-on-button-in-different-screens-in-bootstrap4-or-css)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the code (using your HTML as a basis) for a large button that remains centered on all devices/screens. Click the "run code snippet" button below:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
            <div @fade class="img-wrapper">
                <img [src]="imgPath" class="img-fluid">
                <div class="img-overlay text-center">
                    <button routerLink="/test" 
                            class="btn btn-lg btn-success fill-container text-center testButton" style="width: 34%;">
                        TEST
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it worked well in iPad mode but crashed in iPhone 8 mode ;(

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "crashed"? It works perfectly on my side and it works on ALL screens and devices. So, seems to be something peculiar on your side OR you aren't using the exact code I posted here. Try using my exact code (copy and paste everything) and you'll see it working without any problems.

Comment: I mean to say it becomes ugly. text goes down. I copied and replaced with my code but still no proper effect

Comment: Also important: Notice that I'm not using any of your custom css.

Comment: Notice that I'm not using any of your custom css. That's because I'm only doing what you asked in the question and no more.

Answer (score 1):

To center the text on button: Use

```
class="text-center"
```

Comment: @WASIFon which element you applied Text align ?

Comment: on a button, I applied class text-center. Code updated

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick : Adding class `text-center` to parent div of the `button` tag.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-12">
 <div class="text-center">
  <button routerLink="/test" class="btn btn-success">TEST</button>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Also make sure to include Bootdtrap V4 in `head` tag.

```
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>ICT</title>
 <base href="/">

 <meta name="viewport" charset="utf-8" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
```

Have a look at the this link as well, adding bootstrap to your page: [click me](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_get_started.asp)

Comment: I think no need to add class "text-center" 2 times as parent has center

Comment: yess you dont i just copied his button code, wil edit

Comment: but I am using bootstrap 4, but you are suggesting me to add the reference of bootstrap 3

Comment: sorry just make sure u using that version 4 then ,becuase im not seeing it in your head tag

Comment: it is mentioned in the title bootstrap 4 only

Comment: @WASIF updated, no you have to add it to you HTmL code, i dont see it there??

Comment: actually I am using VS Code to develop angular application. bootstrap 4 ref is there in styles.css file

Comment: ref it in the head tag and see if it makes a difference im not to familiar with VS but im sure u reference the css library of bootstrap using html and not css.

Comment: It works fine but when I customized the height, it became ugly. It's requirement to customize the height of a button

Answer (score -1):

You need to Apply "align-center" class on .img-overlay {} not on Button then it will work